# Index based string matches in python

Tags: python

I have two lists

```
list1 = ['this', 'is', 'the', 'right', 'string']
list2 = ['this', 'is', 'right']
```

After comparison I need to find out another list include only

```
list3 = ['this', 'is']
```

I have tried it up using intersection, I know it is not the proper solution in my case.

```
>>> list(set(list1) & set(list2))
['this', 'is', 'right']
```

It is not the index based comparison.

I need to find the index based comparison. I mean, first compare first words in list1 and list2, if it is match, then take next words in each list then compare that words and so on. If it is not match, then return the matched words only.
Anybody can help me??

Comment: Assuming, list1 and list2 includes different number of words, after comparing two lists i need to find out the index based matched lists. In the above example i need to find list3=['this', 'is']. can you help me??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like noob-style then try this. Easy to understand. That other answer is very much like functional programming, which can be confusing.

```
list3 = list()
for x in range(min(len(list1),len(list2)):
    if list1[x] == list2[x]:
        list3.append(list1[x])
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[x for (x, y) in zip(list1, list2) if x == y]
```

Comment: suppose list1 and list2 contain different number of words, then how to solve it??

Comment: Do you have an ACTUAL problem that question is trying to ask about, or have you not bothered trying the code yet?

Comment: Assuming I'm understanding this properly, if you wanted to modify this so it wouldn't include words past the length of the smaller string, you could do something like n = min(len(list1), len(list2)) and then return that comprehension sliced on [:n]

Comment: @Chad: *Completely* unnecessary.

Comment: Problem here is when you get a match after the first inequality; I believe the OP's description indicates he wants to stop as soon as possible. This wouldn't.